# How to delete virus causing non-empty directory?

Tags: command-line, security, system

There was a virus in my hdd, I thought it wouldn't work in a linux, but even when I do a `sudo rm -rf dir` I get `non empty directory` error.

I even tried renaming it, but still get the same result. It's really weird, I usually get away with `rm -r`

How do I fix this? The filesystem is NTFS

Here is the output if I do an ls -la on Trash-0 (the dir I want to delete)

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 bodhi bodhi    0 Dec 28 09:04 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 bodhi bodhi 8192 Dec 28 09:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 bodhi bodhi    0 Dec 28 08:53 expunged
```

if I do another ls -la on expunged I get:

```
ls: cannot access 'expunged/': No such file or directory
```

but if I use a file manager, I get a dir called 1647516513

Comment: Are you perhaps still running that virused Windows and let's say Linux via VM ? :)

Comment: @GreggD I'm using a live usb linux. I'm just dealing with a persistent black hat hacker :)

Comment: So you want to delete the `expunged` directory or its parent? And what does `expunged` contain (please run the `ls -la` for that one again)?

Comment: @ByteCommander updated my post. The main dir I want to delete is Trash-0, expunged is the subdir of Trash-0

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: @DKBose Ubuntu, I think the virus from android infected it, right now, I'm switching between my live usb linux's, the one used to do the ls command was bodhi

Comment: If it is NTFS, try running chkdsk from a Windows disk or `ntfsfix` on Ubuntu

Comment: This could be happening because another process is accessing the directory. Could you check if there are any PIDs when you do `fuser -m /path/to/directory`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mount the NTFS partition as read-only?